# How to calculate the sum of a Respond (Json) using response.path?

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing, rest-assured-jsonpath

Seem to be struggling to calculate the number of squad members who have the role type of 'PLAYER' by performing my restassured logic against my Json response.

Currently I have a simple setup which hits an endpoint and then executes my query, I can see that the endpoint and response is valid however it seems there is a problem when attempting to filter via my query in order to calculate the total sum of squad members who have a role of 'PLAYER'.

My Rest-assured code:

```
@Test
public void locatePlayerCalculateSum() {
    Response response = given()
            .spec(footballCompetitions_requestSpecification)
            .when().get(EndPoint.TEAMS + EndPoint.SQUAD);
    int sum = response.path("squad.collect { it.role == \"PLAYER\" }.sum()");
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Exception Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.plus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), or(java.lang.Boolean), implies(java.lang.Boolean), and(java.lang.Boolean), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), split(groovy.lang.Closure)

Example JSON response:

````
  "id": 66,
  "area": {
      "id": 2072,
      "name": "England"
  },
  "activeCompetitions": [
      {
          "id": 2021,
          "area": {
              "id": 2072,
              "name": "England"
          },
          "name": "Premier League",
          "code": "PL",
          "plan": "TIER_ONE",
          "lastUpdated": "2019-01-03T23:39:45Z"
      },
      {
          "id": 2001,
          "area": {
              "id": 2077,
              "name": "Europe"
          },
          "name": "UEFA Champions League",
          "code": "CL",
          "plan": "TIER_ONE",
          "lastUpdated": "2018-12-13T18:55:02Z"
      }
  ],
  "name": "Manchester United FC",
  "shortName": "Man United",
  "tla": "MNU",
  "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg",
  "address": "Sir Matt Busby Way Manchester M16 0RA",
  "phone": "+44 (0161) 8688000",
  "website": "http://www.manutd.com",
  "email": "enquiries@manutd.co.uk",
  "founded": 1878,
  "clubColors": "Red / White",
  "venue": "Old Trafford",
  "squad": [
      {
          "id": 3188,
          "name": "David De Gea",
          "position": "Goalkeeper",
          "dateOfBirth": "1990-11-07T00:00:00Z",
          "countryOfBirth": "Spain",
          "nationality": "Spain",
          "shirtNumber": 1,
          "role": "PLAYER"
      },
      {
          "id": 3202,
          "name": "Sergio Romero",
          "position": "Goalkeeper",
          "dateOfBirth": "1987-02-22T00:00:00Z",
          "countryOfBirth": "Argentina",
          "nationality": "Argentina",
          "shirtNumber": null,
          "role": "PLAYER"
      },
      {
          "id": 7942,
          "name": "Lee Grant",
          "position": "Goalkeeper",
          "dateOfBirth": "1983-01-27T00:00:00Z",
          "countryOfBirth": "England",
          "nationality": "England",
          "shirtNumber": 13,
          "role": "PLAYER"
      },
      {
          "id": 3206,
          "name": "Marcos Rojo",
          "position": "Defender",
          "dateOfBirth": "1990-03-20T00:00:00Z",
          "countryOfBirth": "Argentina",
          "nationality": "Argentina",
          "shirtNumber": 16,
          "role": "PLAYER"
      },```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Test
public void locatePlayerCalculateSum() {
    Response response = given()
            .spec(footballCompetitions_requestSpecification)
            .when().get(EndPoint.TEAMS + EndPoint.SQUAD);
    int sum = response.path("squad.count { it.role == 'PLAYER' }");
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```